# Sqlite/SQLServer provider differences

Tags: sqlite, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.2

I have some troubles using sqlite provider to write integration tests.

If I attach a tree of entities to my DbContext, I get relations broken (the same thing with SqlServer provider works).

See sample for more information.

For precision, the PK of the 3 tables are Id + TenantId. TenantId is Set only in the SaveChangesAsync method, depending on the connected User.

If I want it to work on sqlite, I have to set the TenantId on the 3 objects before attaching them to the context... Why is this different with SQL Server provider ?

```cs
public class Store {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int TenantId { get; set; }

    public List<Product> Products { get; set; }
}

public class Product {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int TenantId { get; set; }

    public Store Store { get; set; }
    public int StoreId { get; set; }

    public Category Category { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
}

public class Category {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int TenantId { get; set; }

    public List<Product> Products { get; set; }
}

[Test]
public void Test_Create(){
    var store = new Store();
    store.Products = new List<Product>();

    var product = new Product();
    product.Category = new Category();

    store.Products.Add(product);

    dbContext.Stores.Add(store);

    // fails, product is detached from the Store after attaching to DbContext
    Assert.Single(store.Products);
}
```

Comment: Are you opening the connection and creating the db? see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/testing/sqlite

Comment: I'm using Dependency Injection to instanciate the context and I only attach entities and call SaveChangesAsync. I do not use connections..

Comment: Assuming you're using `datasource=:memory:` for sqlite, then you need to open its connection and create the db. see [first paragraph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/testing/sqlite#writing-tests)

Comment: I'm using a sqlite file, not InMemoryDb. Maybe I was unclear in my question but my problem is that I get some relations lost (here the Product is detached from the Store) after I attach the parent to the context. And this, only happens if I have two FK on the product. If I don't set the Category on the product, the product keeps being in the List<Product> of the store...

Comment: Can you provide more details. First, I don't see where you set `TenantId`. Second, are `Id` properties auto-generated? If they were single PK, that would happen by default, but with composite PK that's unclear. etc. Shortly, please include the fluent configuration.

Comment: The TenantId is Set in the SaveChangesAsync method. Id properties are not autogenerated when I use Sqlite because Sqlite is not able to make composite PK with part auto-increment.